# Renderer2 paste event not firing in IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using IE11 and Angular 4, trying to listen to the paste event. I want to try and put text into a text area when the user selects Ctrl + V but the listen event never fires.

My html:

```
<textarea #textArea>{{text}}</textarea>
```

My typescript:

```
 public text: string = '';
 @ViewChild('textArea', { read: ElementRef }) testElement: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.isIEOrEdge = /msie\s|trident\/|edge\//i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
        if (this.isIEOrEdge) {
          console.log('Element' , this.testElement.nativeElement);
          this.renderer.listen(this.testElement.nativeElement, 'paste', () => {
            console.log('pasting');
            this.InsertNewRowsBeforePaste.bind(this);
        });
        }
      }

    InsertNewRowsBeforePaste(event) {      
        // gets data from clipboard and converts it to an array (1 array element for each line)
        let clipboardData = event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent['clipboardData'].getData('text');
        if (!clipboardData) {
          clipboardData = window['clipboardData'].getData('Text');
        }
        this.text = clipboardData;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the syntax `<textarea (paste)="handlePasteEvent($event)">`? It seems to work in IE11, as you can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vq9aiy).

Comment: I assume that you can use that syntax on any HTML element that allows its content to be modified with the paste command.